# Why don't I see variables when creating a Jupyter Notebook in VSCode using a Julia Kernel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I just installed VSCode 1.59.0 along with the Julia, Jupyter, and Python extensions. I am able to create Jupyter notebooks using either Julia or Python. When I create a notebook using Python, I see the variables I create listed in the Jupyter: Variables tab. When I create a notebook using Julia, however, I do not see the variables I create listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

At the present moment, while Julia is generally supported in the VS Code Extension, this specific feature is not supported. I have an issue on the Microsoft side and Julia VS Code side open here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7224 to hopefully kick start this process.

The Julia VS Code extension does already support this feature outside of Notebooks (when running a ".jl" file) so this should seemingly not be too difficult of a task to port it over to the Jupyter extension, but I am unfamiliar with the level of technical rigor this would require.